can't get the column value. It simply outputs the same number as the column
import sqlite3


def request():
    with sqlite3.connect('sqlite_db.db') as sqlite_conn:
        sql_request = 'SELECT t,80 FROM SS_SZT'
        sql_cursor = sqlite_conn.execute(sql_request)
        res = sql_cursor.fetchall()
        for i in res:
            print(i)

request()

output:
(12.0, 80)
(8.0, 80)
(4.0, 80)
(2.0, 80)
(1.0, 80)
(0.5, 80)
enter image description here
It outputs the value of column t. I just don't understand why it can't output the value of a column with numbers (although they are essentially the same type as the column t, i.e. string)

Your SELECT statement says "please return all records and provide the following values: i - the value in row t, ii - the value 80." What exactly do you want it to return?

@OldBoy well, in general, I would like to get the value based on the user-selected values of column t and some other column(80, 125,.. 630). For example, the user entered t = 8.0 and selected column 80. This would result in a value of 0.04

How did you manage to create a database with numbers as column names? And, more importantly, why?

@OldBoy you can create names that are not normally allowable by enclosing them. Hence the ticked answer using [80], to get the result from the column rather than the literal value 80. See https://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

@MikeT Yes, but why would you?

@OldBoy I don't believe that I would unless providing assistance where such usage had been utilised.

If I understood, you want the result as a tuple of
(t column value, 80 column value) of each row.
try this.
SELECT t, [80] FROM SS_SZT


oh... that easy... thanks

SQL statement seems correct, but I would add a sqlite_conn.cursor() object before execute SQL query:
def request():
     with sqlite3.connect('sqlite_db.db') as sqlite_conn:
        sql_request = 'SELECT t,80 FROM SS_SZT'
        sql_cursor = sqlite_conn.cursor()
        sql_cursor.execute(sql_request)
        res = sql_cursor.fetchall()
        for i in res:
            print(i)

